# android accessing button in custom adapter

Tags: android

I want to access a button from an activity in a lazyadapter's getview( that is to make clickable from lazyadapter) is there any method to do that? The button click brings the user to the next screen. Please if someone has any idea or code.

Comment: I answered below just you will replace the text into Button and then you use this list view in your activity...

Comment: My adapter class is separate and i did what you posted below. The @Naveen Kumar problem is in onclick listener what should i do to access the activity button click method. Just like we do in oop `classname obj=bew classname(); obj.btn(); ` but here in android this thing wouldnt work.

Comment: You want access the button in activity i think for that you just declare that button into static variable in activity and then use that buttonn in getview method like ActivityName.buttonName.setonclicklistener.

Comment: But if you try this above logic you should not use the onclick listener  in your Activity..

Comment: @Naveen Kumar getting null pointer exception now what you have said i did

Comment: yes am not using onclick in activity

Comment: and there is a mehtod i am accessing in that button click like obj.testMethod();

Comment: You just declare the variable in your activity then use the variable like Button btn = (Button) findViewByid(R.id.btnName); you just make sure you wrote this line on your Activity and declare the button variable as a Public static variable and use it

Comment: If possible then post your code here..

Comment: yes did exactly what you have said above

Comment: And then Make sure if you getting any variable inside the method other than new Variable If you use any variable inside that method already used variable na it will give null pointer exception..I think you are facing this  problem...

Answer (score 0):

**You just follow this code on get your Click function and call your next activity in the onclick listener....**

```
 CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
 mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

 public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
 public Context context;
 public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
super(context, resource);
this.mlist = mlist;
this.context = context;
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
 return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
 return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
        // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
        // your listview

    }
});
return convertView;
}

}
```